# 2 while loops in a function in C

Tags: c

Is it possible to run 2 while loops in the same function?
Only one of the while loops works. If I remove the first the one, the second one will work and if I remove the second one, the first one will work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FILE_NAME "results.txt"

void analyseText(int character[], int i, FILE *fptr, int *sum, int a)
{
    while ((i = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)
    {
        if (i >= 'a' && i <= 'z')
            character[(i - 'a')]++;
        if (i >= 'A' &&  i <= 'Z')
            character[(i - 'A')]++;

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            printf("%c: %d\n", i + 'a', character[i]);

        }
        while (1)
        {
            int result = fscanf(fptr, "%d", &a);
            if (result == EOF) {
                break;
            }
            else if (result == 1) {
                *sum += a;
            }
            else {

                fscanf(fptr, "%*c");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's 2 declarations of `i` ?

Comment: Do you think it has to do something with that?

Comment: Dare I ask why `i` is a function parameter? Just curious. Regardless, the actual sample *data*, and expectations of what this function is *supposed to be doing* should be part of your posted question. The inner while-loop looks broken. That loop will only drop on stream error/EOF, and in the latter case, its all over for the outer loop as well.

Comment: You can nest as many `while` as you want, as long as they as their go-conditions are relevant.

Comment: Ok can we write the code in a different way but the function is still the same?

Answer (score 2):

I've ran your program and it seems the second while loop terminates the function. The second while loop will read the characters from the file and will do so until it reach the end, then will exit. Both while loop executes, but the first one executes only once and the second executes till will reach the end of the file. Maybe it is a logic bug there?

Also, are you trying to read some numbers in the second loop, the result will never pe 1 if there are only characters in the file.

Comment: The first while loop counts each character and the second one sums the numbers together. 
And yes there are both numbers and text in the file

Comment: Tried the new configuration, if your file has a something like char number1 number2 ... on each line, in the second loop you should check for both end of the file, but also for end of the line, to start the loop for the next char.

Answer (score 0):

You have an (almost) infinite loop inside an (almost) infinite loop, with just about the same stop condition for both.

One of them will run "forever" and when it triggers the stop condition the other will also stop, giving the appearance of just one of the loops running.

2 loops

```
enter infinite loop1
    do some stuff one once
    enter infinite loop2
        do some stuff two "forever"
```

when you remove the inner loop

```
enter infinite loop1
    do some stuff one "forever"
```

when you remove the outer loop

```
enter infinite loop2
    do some stuff two "forever"
```